# Send Basic Autherization in vollery request

Tags: android, android-volley

Hello I am trying to send Basic Authorization in volley request. I tried this almost 7-8 months ago and it was working fine..

but I don't know what goes wrong now when I try to send request with authorization header and I always get 403 error. and when I tried to hit the url from hurl.it the it works fine.. can someone tell what is wrong with my request.

This is how I am adding Authorization header in volley request

```
public class VolleyRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {

    String email, pass;
    boolean saveCookeis;

    public VolleyRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                         Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener,
                         String email, String pass, boolean saveCookie) {
        super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.email = email;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.saveCookeis = saveCookie;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String auth = "";
        try {
            auth = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(
                    (this.email + ":" + this.pass).getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        params.put("Authorization", auth);
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (saveCookeis) {
            try {
                String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

                ApplicationController.getInstance().checkSessionCookie(
                        response.headers);

                return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
            }
        }
        return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);

    }
}
```

**Screenshots From post man**

[image: This is how I added auth data]

[image: This is how I am adding data]

[image: This is the server response]

[Sample data can found here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-sxBwyYfZm7dF9GYmhfTzM2OGc/view?usp=sharing)

Now this code is not working. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Pls post your `hurl.it` screenshot

Comment: @BNK Please check updated question... I have added the screenshots from postman please check.

Comment: I think you should add "Basic " string as the answer of @MichaelStoddart, for example in Postman you will find `Basic Z3VzdGF2ZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbToxMjM0` in Headers tab

Comment: let me try and i will let you know...

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I was on leaves.. i will try it in this week and i will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new JSONObject(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           //Handle response
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         //Handle Error
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return super.getParams();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(
                    "Authorization",
                    String.format("Basic %s", Base64.encodeToString(
                            String.format("%s:%s", username, password).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)));
            return params;
        }
    };

    jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```